# Is phonegap index.js file really necessary in a web application?

Tags: phonegap-build

Please am new to programming and am trying to build my first mobile app. the question is do i need the phonegap index.js file, cant i just write my code without it like normal jQuery code in a website? I don't really understand how to put the code in the index.js file.The code is very basic, nothing complicated.  Thank you

Comment: The index.js file is not necessary. You can put your javascript code where you prefer.

Comment: oh thank you very much, i would try it out

Comment: i have tried it, its working but i still have a lot of work to do on it. thanks really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ifeoluwa king,
only two files are needed to produce for *Phonegap Build* or *Phonegap CLI*. The two files are:

1. index.html
2. config.xml

The third file required file, which must be include in the index.html, is *phonegap.js*. With *Phonegap Build*, the system automatically provides the file. With *Phonegap CLI*, I have no experience with this, but according to this [blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/11/13/phonegap-cli-3-6-3/) it has been added to your bundle. In addition, you NEED TO SWITCH THE NAME to ***cordova.js*** - Again, read the [blog post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/11/13/phonegap-cli-3-6-3/) for details.

**Appended 2015/09/02**
On the original question, *index.js* is NOT needed. The file is created as a default; other possible names include, *default.js* and *app.js*.

Comment: Alright thank you. I used both the index.html and config.xml and it worked fine.